# Disabling ligatures in xelatex like rmligs

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

Ligatures set by Latex are often wrong in German (i.e. between combined
words like "Auflaufform"). To set these words correct I often use rmligs
which is a great tool to disable ligatures when the use of them would be
wrong.

rmligs places a "| between the letters of a "wrong ligature".

Unfortunately the use of "| doesn't work for me if I use xelatex and
fontspec (it seems to require babel).

Is there a correct method to disable ligatures when I'm forced to use
xelatex and fontspec?

This is not a question about disabling only specific ligatures or disable ligatures generally.

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX an option for you? If it is, you could use the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package (with language option `ngerman`) to suppress ligatures selectively.

Comment: What's the problem in using `babel` along with `fontspec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried running `rmligs` on the following file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Auflaufform
\end{document}
```

This resulted in writing out

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Auf"|lauf"|form
\end{document}
```

which I ran XeLaTeX on, getting

[image]

The same result is obtained if the original file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[babelshorthands]{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Auflaufform
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got an error clash if using babel and polyglossia together and an Auflauf"|form as result. Now it works fine.

Comment: Hm. With texlive 2017 on a mac the polyglossa example produces ligatures for me. I would much prefer an automatic solution with xelatex.

Answer (score 3):

If using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX is an option for you, then running LuaLaTeX on

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,babel,selnolig}
\begin{document}
Auflaufform 

auffällig 

Stoffisolator
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

without the need to run `rmligs` (or some other pre-preprocessor) on the input file.

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know and I will give it a try.

Comment: @Sverre - Many thanks for the edit! :-)